# How to implement a recursive function using lambda expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, factorial

My task is to implement the `factorial` function using just a lambda expression.
Here's what I have tried

```
fact = lambda n: if n == 0 return 1 else ...
```

I'm stuck!

**Edit:**
*fix if statement syntax error*

```
fact = lambda n: 1 if n == 0 else ...
```

I'm stuck again..

How to do it?

Comment: The title and your question are not the same thing. Do you need to implement factorial with a `lambda` or do you need to do it with recursion using a `lambda`?

Comment: You can implement factorial using recursion. There is not a difference in what you're saying.

Comment: You can also implement it without recursion. An iterative approach is much better for this. For example: `fact = lambda n: reduce(operator.mul, range(1,n+1))`

Comment: That's why I did title it "recursive" because I want the recursive implementation to showcase the use of lambda expressions in that case, but not the iterative one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach is to use the name of the variable you assign the `lambda` into as the way to call the code recursively:

```
>>> fact = lambda n: 1 if n <= 0 else n * fact(n - 1)
>>> fact(10)
3628800
>>>
```

There are more complex solutions involving passing `lambda` expressions to `lambda` expressions or Y-combinators.  Your approach was already doomed by the use of an `if ... else ...` *statement*.  A `lambda` expression can only contain other *expressions*, not *statements*, so you'd need to use the  `... if ... else ...` *expression* syntax instead.

Comment: Yeah actually the "if statement I did" was a mistake i meant what you did. Thanks for your solution; I didn't know one can access the variable before it's finished being defined.